# Kotlin group objects into parent child relationships

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement a comment session in an Android App. my api gives comments list like this:

```
"comments": [{'comid':"44", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "12"}, 
{'comid':"55", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "44"},
{'comid':"66", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "55"}]
```

Here. Second and third comments are child and grandchild respectively.
How can I convert this into a `listOf(Comment())` class object like below into parent->children->grandchildren: (relationship based on `parentid`)

```
data class Comment(
    val comid: String,
    val postid: String,
    val parentid: String,
    val children: List<Comment>)
```

result shall be like:

```
comments = [ Comment(), Comment(listOf(Child(), Child())), 
Comment(listOf(Child(listOf(Grandchild(), Grandchild())))), Comment(), Comment(), ... ]
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the json string started with [， try：

```
var strList:String = "[{\"comments\": [{'comid':\"44\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"12\", 'name':\"Alice\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Alice\"}, \n" +
        "{'comid':\"55\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"44\", 'name':\"Boby\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Boby\"},\n" +
        "{'comid':\"66\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"55\", 'name':\"Cris\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Cris\"}]}]"

fun transferList() :List<Comment>{
    var list:List<Comment> = ArrayList();
    val gson = Gson()
    val comment: Comment = gson.fromJson(str, Comment::class.java)
    list = gson.fromJson(
        strList,
        object : TypeToken<List<Comment?>?>() {}.getType()
    )
    return list
}
```

---

try to use https://github.com/google/gson

```
data class Comment(
    val comid: String,
    val postid: String,
    val parentid: String,
    val name: String,
    val content: String,
    val comments: List<Comment>){
    
    var str:String = "{\"comments\": [{'comid':\"44\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"12\", 'name':\"Alice\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Alice\"}, \n" +
            "{'comid':\"55\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"44\", 'name':\"Boby\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Boby\"},\n" +
            "{'comid':\"66\", 'postid': \"12\", 'parentid': \"55\", 'name':\"Cris\", 'content': \"lorem ipsum Cris\"}]}"

    fun transfer() :Comment{
        val gson = Gson()
        val comment: Comment = gson.fromJson(str, Comment::class.java)
        return comment
    }
}
```

Comment: can this group the data based on `parentid` into parent->child->grandchild relationship? eg: `Comment('comid':"44", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "12", 'name':"Alice", 'content': "lorem ipsum Alice", [Comment('comid':"55", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "44", 'name':"Boby", 'content': "lorem ipsum Boby", [Comment('comid':"66", 'postid': "12", 'parentid': "55", 'name':"Cris", 'content': "lorem ipsum Cris")])])`. Here only one parent, child and grandchild. so `val children: List<Comment>` have only one member each. otherwise a list with several elements may come

Comment: let me clarify further. the result shall be `comments = [Comment([Child(), Child()]), Comment([Child([Grandchild(), Grandchild()])]), Comment(), Comment(), ...]`

Comment: May i ask if the data you want to convert is a json array that starts with a bracketed symbol [ ?

Comment: hi@binrebin，i just updated my answer,pls kindly refer

Comment: i think this gist https://gist.github.com/binrebin/af66ddbb486ea3c2dcd64870107cdcf4 can somehow solve my problem provided there is a Gson Factory. But I dont know how to connet, `fun findChildren()` to set value of field `children`. can you help